# How do you do GRPC authentication in an istio mTLS setup?

Tags: go, grpc, istio, mtls

I have bunch of GRPC microservices and they are using self signed certs. I add authentication info to the GRPC channel which is then used to identify endpoints and provide right services.

Now I want migrate to Istio mTLS.

In phase one, I got Istio to BYPASS all GRPC connections and my services works as it is now.

In Phase two, I want to hand off TLS to Istio, but I am stuck on how to pass the authentication information to GRPC?

How do you handle auth in Istio mTLS setup?

GRPC can support [other authentication mechanisms](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/#extending-grpc-to-support-other-authentication-mechanisms) Has anyone used this to inject Istio auth info to GRPC? any other suggestions on how you implemented this in your setup

I am using go-lang just in case if this can be useful to provide any additional information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by generating JWT token for my requests, and injected the token using an Interceptor. Took inspiration from [GRPC interceptor for authorization with jwt](https://dev.to/techschoolguru/use-grpc-interceptor-for-authorization-with-jwt-1c5h)

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this is using `grpc.WithInsecure()`, this way you don't have to add certificates to your services, since `istio-proxy` containers in your pods will TLS terminate any incoming connections.

Client side:

```
conn, _ := grpc.Dial("localhost:50051", grpc.WithInsecure())
```

Server side:

```
s := grpc.NewServer()
lis, _ := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:50051")

// error handling omitted
s.Serve(lis)
```

If you still need to use TLS for on-prem deployments, etc. you can simply use a configuration option to specify this such as:

```
var conn *grpc.ClientConn
var err error
// error handling omitted do not copy paste

if ( config.IstioEnabled ) {
    conn, err = grpc.Dial("localhost:50051", grpc.WithInsecure())

} else {
    creds, _ := credentials.NewClientTLSFromFile(certFile, "")
    conn, err = grpc.Dial("localhost:50051", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(creds))

}
```

[Reference](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When I do `WithInsecure()` I lose the capability to add credentials, which I am using to identify the endpoints (I use `WithPerRPCCredentials()`which adds auth header to requests).

Comment: Ah I see, here is an article that may be useful: https://medium.com/utility-warehouse-technology/grpc-client-authentication-bf899ac8ada8

Comment: The link hit a pay wall